# How to send all options from a checkbox list/radio box list/ select option list to server along with the selected one by php?

Tags: php, forms

I have a code what has a simple select/options and some check boxes i want to send to server using PHP script, all the options including the option selected ( so i cant make them all selected ) so how do i do it?

Comment: Do you want to select all options in select and checkbox also while submitting the form?

Comment: `all the options including the option selected ( so i cant make them all selected )` Please can you elaborate?

Comment: No, i just need to know on server what options were there, as i will be generating them dynamically using google maps (current location)

Comment: Also i want a preferred nearby location so i want user to select one options but also want to know at server what options were generated so i need all options (unchecked also ) to be sent via form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your dropdown as it is.

```
<select id="location" name="location">
.
.
.
.
</seelct>
```

Then add another one dropdown as hidden `(display:none;)` without any options. This dropdown will be filled with options when clicking submit button.

On submit button click action add below js code,

In js:

```
 $('#location option').clone().appendTo('#near_location');// copied all options
   var index = $('#location ').get(0).selectedIndex; // remove selected
   $('#near_location option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
    return true;
```

Now you will get the selected option in `$_POST["location"]` and un-selected values in `$_POST["near_loaction"]`.

Comment: But then how will i identify which option was selected initially( i previously wanted to say that there is one way to send all options to send all of them by selecting all of them ) but i do want only one selected by user as preferred. and want to be able to recognize that option at server. using this method all will be the same.

Comment: Then you have to pass unselected options separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can save generated options on the server via session or database and load it after submit.

Comment: but i have all options in js. how will i store them in sessions or database before submit using php.

Comment: you can use jquery. also you can create hidden element and put all options there. this is better solution!